# Is it possible to clear app data in react native programmatically

Tags: react-native

There was a bug in my react native app, I handled it a new release, Unfortunately this issue has not been solved for the users who made the update, It has been solved for the users who recently downloaded the app only.
I thought about clearing the app data, is there a way for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you store the data.

If you use Async Storage, you need to use API of removeItem. [Reference](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#removeitem)

If your data are stored at your app's folder or public folder, you can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to delete them.